# How to set cursor in runtime with sendmessage?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to set cursor shape dynamically when specific event occurs. for examaple, button in disable state, the cursor will arrow. then, when edit control fullfill requirement, button should enable to click and the cursor shape will change to hand.

```
HCURSOR lCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND);
HCURSOR hCursor = SetCursor(lCursor);

Button* btnLogin = new Button(hWnd);
HWND  hBtnLogin = btnLogin->getHandle();

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, (WPARAM) hBtnLogin, (LPARAM) hCursor);
```

Comment: WM_SETCURSOR has nothing to do with the cursor shape, it's a notification https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor *"Sent to a window if the mouse causes the cursor to move within a window and mouse input is not captured."*

Comment: @SimonMourier so, what the function to set control cursor shape? i search in google. i found out SetCursor function only.

Comment: That's all there is.

Comment: @SimonMourier if so my thinking  is to detect cursor position in control. let's cursor in button login  and it set cursor shape to specific. so the problem here, not SETCURSOR mesasge. but the function that change cursor shape.

Comment: You control the cursor shape by responding to the `WM_SETCURSOR` message. By default (that is when passing the message to the default window procedure), the system will set the cursor shape to the one specified in the corresponding window class. If you want to override that behavior, work is required.